# How do I detect and wait for an overlay in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a spinner overlay that appears on top of page and I must wait for it to finish loading. After it goes away, then I can click elements. However, when I perform a test to see if the element is clickable, it always returns true. I have to manually add a hard coded wait time for the spinner to disappear. The problem is it is very flaky and indeterminate. Sometimes it takes longer than the hard coded time and produces an error. Of course when it takes less time, then it still has to wait and is very slow and wastes time. This is the code:

```
echo "Finding Advanced\n";
$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::elementToBeClickable( WebDriverBy::partialLinkText('Advanced') ) );
sleep(3); // spinner
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText("Advanced"))->click();
```

This is the error message when the spinner overlay takes longer than expected:

```
Finding Advanced
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnknownServerException' with message 'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (89, 127). Other element would receive the click: <div id="socialLoader" class="overlay" style="display: block; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.152)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

---

I tried the following

```
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('button.xBtn.remove'))->click();
sleep(1); // spinner
echo "Finding Advanced\n";
$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::invisibilityOfElementLocated( WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader') )); // spinner
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText("Advanced"))->click();
```

and got this

> Finding Advanced
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnknownServerException' with message 'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (89, 127). Other element would receive the click: ...

---

I tried this

```
// sleep(1); // spinner
echo "Finding Status Active\n";
$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::elementToBeClickable( WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader') ) );
$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::invisibilityOfElementLocated( WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader') )); // spinner
```

and got this

> Finding Status Active
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'TimeOutException' in C:\Users\finance.operations\Desktop\Teads\php-webdriver\lib\WebDriverWait.php:69

Answer (score 2):

Look at the problem from a different angle - wait for the spinner overlay to be no longer attached to DOM using `WebDriverExpectedCondition::stalenessOf` or to be invisible using `WebDriverExpectedCondition::invisibilityOfElementLocated`.

Which expected condition to use depends on what is happening with the spinner after - is it being removed from the DOM completely or just becoming invisible.

Comment: It's always better to apply positive locators. For example, instead of waiting for the throbber to disappear, wait for the overlay to appear. Negative locators can still suffer from race conditions the same way the initial condition does. Think of it this way, a human when interaction with your application isn't waiting for the spinner. He's waiting for the dialogue to interact with. The spinner is just a side effect of what we really want.

Comment: @JohnCartwright that's a great point, thank you. Looking at this problem through the negative locators may also reveal a better solution to the problem, or provide a better understanding.

Comment: Ok I tried `$spinner = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader'));
$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::stalenessOf( $spinner ) );` but it gave an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'TimeOutException' in .../WebDriverWait.php:69`. I tried `$driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::invisibilityOfElementLocated( WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader') )); 
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText("Advanced"))->click();` and it still gives the same error `Element is not clickable at point. Other element would receive the click` sometimes.

Comment: @JohnCartwright The element is already loaded underneath the overlay. The element that I want loads fast. But the overlay imposes itself for some reason and block any clicks. Testing for the element that I seek always returns true, because it exists, but yet is not clickable.

Comment: Ok I solved it with `sleep(1);
    $driver->wait(10)->until( WebDriverExpectedCondition::invisibilityOfElementLocated( WebDriverBy::id('socialLoader') ));` and I saved 2 seconds on each element search, so that's a positive. Thanks, I didn't know about `invisibilityOfElementLocated`.

Comment: You should wait until it appears first and get rid of the sleep(1) statement. Then wait for the expected condition of invisibility.